# Passing options to JS function with Amber

Tags: smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

I'm trying to write the equivalent of:

`$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "y" });`

in Amber smalltalk.

My guess was: `'#draggable' asJQuery draggable: {'axis' -> 'y'}` but that's not it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not working on vanilla 0.9.1, but working on master at least last two months ago is:

```
'#draggable' asJQuery draggable: #{'axis' -> 'y'}
```

and afaict this is the recommended way.

P.S.: `#{ 'key' -> val. 'key2' -> val }` is the syntax for inline creation of `HashedCollection`, which is implemented (from the aforementioned two-month ago fix) so that only public (aka enumerable) properties are the HashedCollection keys. Before the fix also all the methods were enumerable, which prevented to use it naturally in place of JavaScript objects.

Comment: Cool. It works. That's what I was aiming for. Funny that passing a Dictionary doesn't work.

Comment: `Dictionary` is more complicated object (anything can be key, not just string, etc.). It is implemented to fulfill the Smalltalk contract, but it uses helper instance variables etc. to achieve this; IOW, it's JavaScript implementation keys are different from its logical, semantic keys. Not so for `HashedCollection` - it can only have strings as keys and was meant as a wrapper around JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2):

**herby**'s excellent answer points out the **recommended** way to do it. Appearently, there is now Dictionary-literal support (see his comment below). Didn't know that :-)

### Old / Alternate way of doing it

For historical reasons, or for users not using the latest master version, this is an alternative way to do it:

```
options :=  <{}>. 
options at: #axis put: 'y'.
'#draggable' asJQuery draggable: options.
```

The first line constructs an empty JavaScript object (it's really an `JSObjectProxy`).

The second line puts the string "y" in the slot "axis". It has the same effect as:

```
options.axis = "y"; // JavaScript
```

Lastly, it is invoked, and passed as a parameter.

### Array-literals vs Dictionaries

What you were doing didn't work because in modern Smalltalk (Pharo/Squeak/Amber) the curly-brackets are used for array-literals, not as an object-literal as they are used in JavaScript.

If you evaluate (print-it) this in a Workspace:

```
{ #elelemt1. #element2. #element3 }.
```

You get:

```
a Array (#elelemt1 #element2 #element3)
```

As a result, if you have something that *looks* like a JavaScript object-literal in reality it is an Array of Association(s). To illustrate I give you this snippet, with the results of print-it on the right:

```
arrayLookingLikeObject := { #key1 -> #value1. #key2 -> #value2. #key3 -> #value3}.

arrayLookingLikeObject class. "==> Array"
arrayLookingLikeObject first class. "==> Association"
arrayLookingLikeObject "==> a Array (a Association a Association a Association)"
```

I wrote about it here:

http://smalltalkreloaded.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/javascript-objects-back-and-forth.html

Comment: FYI: It is not a `Dictionary` literal, it is `HashedCollection` literal, which is superclass of `Dictionary` in Smalltalk hierarchy, has the limitation that only strings can be keys, and is implemented so that it wraps an actual JavaScript object.